# Jackson conflicting setters, even with @JsonIgnore and @JsonProperty

Tags: java, jackson, java-11

I'm at a complete loss here. I have a class with overloaded setters for a property, and for the life of me cannot get Jackson to pick a correct setter. Stripping out the things not needed from the class, here's the base of what I've got:

```
class TestDTO {
    
      @Setter(onMethod_={@JsonProperty})
      @JsonProperty
      protected CustomWrapper wrappedValues = new CustomWrapper();

      @JsonIgnore
      @XmlTransient
      public RecordAudit setWrappedValues(List<WrappedObject> wrappedValues) {
         this.customWrapper = new CustomWrapper(wrappedValues);
         return this;
      }

      @JsonIgnore
      @XmlTransient
      public RecordAudit setWrappedValues(CustomWrapper customWrapper) {
         this.customWrapper = customWrapper;
         return this;
      }
}
```

I have tried every combination I can think of of `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonProperty`. I've tried just adding `@JsonProperty` to the `@Setter` annotation, I've tried only adding `@JsonIgnore` to the two custom setters, I've tried only `@JsonProperty` on the field itself, but no matter what I try, I get the following error:

```
Conflicting setter definitions for property "wrappedValues": ...#setWrappedValues(1 params) vs ...#setWrappedValues(1 params)
```

Does anyone have any ideas what's going on here? Using Jackson 2.12.4, so I think just `@JsonProperty` should be all that's needed, but as I mentioned above, that still results in the same error.

This is on JDK 11 if that makes a difference, I'm still new to 11, so am not sure how much that affects this.

Comment: @Setter(onMethod_={@JsonProperty}) - is this annotation from Lombok?

Comment: Yeah, I've never used it before today, but it seems this will generate a setter, and then add `@JsonProperty` onto the setter. As mentioned below, it may not be generating a setter because I already have two custom ones below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark setter you want to use as `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter`.

```java
class TestDTO {
    
      protected CustomWrapper wrappedValues = new CustomWrapper();

      public RecordAudit setWrappedValues(List<WrappedObject> wrappedValues) {
         this.customWrapper = new CustomWrapper(wrappedValues);
         return this;
      }

      @JsonSetter
      public RecordAudit setWrappedValues(CustomWrapper customWrapper) {
         this.customWrapper = customWrapper;
         return this;
      }
}
```

P.S. Your `@Setter` aren't generating anything since there are methods with name `setWrappedValues`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense for why the `@Setter` may not be working, but unfortunately adding just the `@JsonSetter` results in the same error. Looking at its documentation, it looks like it's very analogous to `@JsonProperty`, so my guess is whatever my issue is causing that to not work as well.

Comment: I've checked on Jackson databind 2.12.4 and it works for me

Comment: Marking as accepted, works for me as well.... I was importing ObjectMapper from codehaus and importing annotations from fasterxml.... Thank you for this suggestion and the testing, made me start looking into configuration issues to find that issue.